# Reduce the width of cells in a table using talltblr

Tags: tables, width, cell

Does anybody know how to reduce the width of cells? I couldn't find it.

Here is a preview of the problem. The width is too important for the datas.
[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bookmark, tabularx, varwidth, nicematrix, array, tabularray, ragged2e, booktabs, makecell}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}C}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{table*}[h]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Pénétration d'Internet et sa croissance en Chine continentale, de 2007 à 2012.},
  label = {tab:?},
note{a} = {Donnée en points}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = { l *{2}{c}}
                  }
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    \textbf{Années}
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {\textbf{Chine continentale (en \%)}}\\
        &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}{\textbf{Pénétration\\d'Internet}} & \SetCell[r=2]{c}{\textbf{Croissance par rapport à\\l'année précédente}} \\ 

\textbf{2006}    & 13,3  &  \SetCell{bg=gray} \\
\textbf{2007}    & 20,3   & 52,6\\ 
\textbf{2008}    & 28,9   &  42,4\\ 
\textbf{2009}    & 37,2   &  28,7\\ 
\textbf{2010}    & 44,2   & 18,8\\ 
\textbf{2011}    & 49,6   &  12,2 \\
\textbf{2012}    & 54,5   &  9,9 \\
%---------------------------------------------------
\hline
\textbf{2007-2012}    & 564\TblrNote{a}   &  5.2\\
\end{talltblr}\\
    \end{table*}
    \justifying \normalsize
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you merge cells with `\SetCell[r=...]{}` you need the number of  rows in the table, not the number of lines of text. One row in the table can have multiple lines of text.

For example your first cell spans two table rows, so you need `r=2` not `r=3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tabularray}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h]
\centering
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {Pénétration d'Internet et sa croissance en Chine continentale, de 2007 à 2012.},
  label = {tab:?},
  note{a} = {Donnée en points}
]{
  hlines, vlines,
  colspec = {lQ[c]Q[c]},
  row{1-2}={font=\bfseries},
  column{1}={font=\bfseries}
}
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Années & \SetCell[c=2]{} \textbf{Chine continentale (en \%)}\\
&   {Pénétration\\ d'Internet} &  {Croissance par rapport à\\ l'année précédente} \\ 
2006    & 13,3  &  \SetCell{bg=gray} \\
2007    & 20,3   & 52,6\\ 
2008    & 28,9   &  42,4\\ 
2009    & 37,2   &  28,7\\ 
2010    & 44,2   & 18,8\\ 
2011    & 49,6   &  12,2 \\
2012    & 54,5   &  9,9 \\
%---------------------------------------------------
\hline
2007-2012    & 564\TblrNote{a}   &  5.2\\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aaah thank you! I thought it was the effective number of lines taken by the text. :)

Comment: @Guillaume You're welcome!